# Junit Test failing due to Parent applicationContext bean

Tags: spring, maven, junit

My test case is failing with the below error :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'acesFormFactory' defined in class path resource [/META-INF/aces-beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'promotionMarshaller' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'promotionMarshaller' is defined
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:629)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)

Now here is my Test Class :

```
    @WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/aces-beans.xml",
        "classpath:/META-INF/aces-flow-config.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class ApplicationContextTest {
    @Resource
    private AcesFormFactory acesFormFactory;

    @Test
    public void paymentFormFactoryAvailable() {
        assertThat(acesFormFactory, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(acesFormFactory, is(instanceOf(AcesFormFactoryImpl.class)));
    }
}
```

Here promotionMarshaller in injected in acesFormFactory as a constructor arg in aces-beans.xml. And the definition of promotionMarshaller is there in ApplicationContext.xml of webapp-control which is there in the dependency list of pom.xml of the current component.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>webapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp-control</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>webapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp-control</artifactId>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I don't get why the parent application context is not getting loaded while running the Junit Test case. Please look into this as I am stuck here for 2 days now.

Here's a snippet from aces-beans.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="acesFormFactory"
        class="com.company.impl.AcesFormFactoryImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="checkoutPromotionMarshaller" />
    </bean>
```

My environment is Spring 3.2.1, Junit 4, JDK 1.7, Maven 3.0.4

Comment: Please post the `aces-beans.xml`.

Comment: I have added aces-beans.xml. Please have a look...